# Exported TSV file has whitespace between each character while using text processor(Perl CSV or find/findstr DOS)

Tags: perl, find, export-to-csv, findstr, spotfire

I have a TSV file exported from an application (Spotfire webplayer using Internet Explorer). While viewing that file in Notepad++ or notepad everything looks good (PFA the snapshot).

But If i input the file to a Perl based CSV Parser(TSV actually) or simply use find/findstr MS-DOS commands, each character actually appears with a whitespace.

I am trying to exclude few lines (based on specific dates) but due to this issue, I am unable to do that.

[image]

Comment: The text in that screenshot is ungodly small. Instead of an image, cut and paste a snippet of the actual text into your question.

Comment: Is the file encoded in UTF-16 or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is Unicode encoded. (Notepad++ is showing it as "UCS-2 Little Endian" in the status bar.) You need to tell Perl what the encoding is and decode the data while reading from the file.

```
use Encode qw(decode);
# read from file into $octets...
my $chars = decode('UCS-2LE', $octets, Encode::FB_CROAK);
```

Comment: Got this error - **UCS-2BE:Unicode character fffe is illegal at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Text/CSV_PP.pm line 679.**

 `my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => '\t', binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/,quote_space => 0 });
open my $in_fh, "<:encoding(UCS-2)", $CSVFile or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>', $tmpCSVFile or die $!;
my $cnt=1;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($in_fh)) {
 my $date = $row->[0]; 
 # do checks here....
 $csv->print($out_fh, $row);
}`

Comment: How do convert or save the file from USC-2 to ANSI encoded?

Comment: @Siva: You're using the wrong encoding layer. `FFFE` is the BOM for a little-endian file, but you're using a big-endian encoding. Change `UCS-2` to `UCS-2LE`.